# Transfer a key and respective value from one dict to another

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a main dict with a certain number of keys e.i.

```
dict1 = {NAME: John, Second_Name: Doe}
```

I have a series of this dicts and all of them are inside a list.
Is there a way to loop through this list and create a list with dictionaries with, for example, only the key NAME and respective value? Is there a straightforward way to do this?

PS: I'm using dict1 as an example as in my program I'm working with dicts with a lot more keys.

Comment: What is the value contained in `carregamento["geonames"]`?

Comment: ForeverWintr I figured the problem. The list with the dicts was being created inside a list so the program was raising that help.
Thanks for all the help to you and @zondo

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a list comprehension:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'NAME': 'John', 'Second_Name': 'Doe'},
    {'NAME': 'Tim', 'Second_Name': 'Doh'},
    {'NAME': 'Mark', 'Second_Name': 'Dough'},
]

names_only = [{'NAME': d['NAME']} for d in list_of_dicts]
```

Comment: That seems a good answer. If I want to add a set of keys instead of just one do you know what changes should I do to this code for that?

Comment: @NunoChicória: Same idea.  Pretend you are in a `for` loop.  You can create however long a dictionary you want.  You might use `{'NAME': d['NAME'], 'SecondName': d['SecondName']}`

Comment: @zondo I'm getting this error (TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str). Do you know how could I work around this?

Comment: @NunoChicória, that error probably means that `d` is actually a list, not a dictionary. You should edit your question to show what you're trying.

Comment: @zondo I edit the question now with the code I have and explaining the problem I am facing.

Comment: @NunoChicória: Your edit to the question has invalidated your answers.  It is enough different that I would put it in a separate question.  You can rollback the edit and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[{'NAME': d['NAME']} for d in dictionaries]
```

That will raise a `KeyError` if `NAME` is not found.  You can use a default instead like this:

```
[{'NAME': d.get('NAME', 'unknown')} for d in dictionaries]
```

for each dictionary, `d`, in `dictionaries`, it creates a dictionary with a single key, `NAME`, that has the value of `d['NAME']`.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I don't really know what I'm doing.

Extending on @ForeverWintr's answer, to allow the copying of keys which don't necessarily exist, which I think OP was asking for in the comments:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'NAME': 'John', 'Second_Name': 'Doe'},
    {'NAME': 'Tim', 'Second_Name': 'Doh'},
    {'NAME': 'Mark', 'Second_Name': 'Dough', 'SECRET_HANDSHAKE': True},
]

filter = ['NAME', 'SECRET_HANDSHAKE']
names_only = [{
         k: v
         for k, v in d.items()
         if k in filter
    } for d in list_of_dicts
]
```

I've no idea if that `k in filter` thing is efficient.  Maybe there's a better way.  It seems like you'd want to pre-cook `filter` into a structure that was more efficient to search.  Maybe another dict?